# how can I stop vi from continuing comments on the next line?

Tags: vim, centos, vi

I'm using vim on Centos7 with :set compatible, to make it behave like vi.

If I start a line with a # (e.g. to make a comment in a bash script), when I press return the next line also begins with #.

I don't have this annoying behavior on mac os, nor on solaris nor on cygwin. Why is Vim doing this on Centos and how can I stop it?

Comment: Check `:help 'formatoptions`

Comment: As you want pure `vi` behavior why do not start `vi` instead of `vim`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using vim or neovim. Remove the `r` from `formatoptions`, e.g. instead of using `:set fo=tcrqn` use `:set fo=tcqn`.

More information:

```
:h fo-table
```